# Proof and intuition for sampling without replacement?

Tags: combinatorics

Consider this:

[image: th]

I am trying to understand this instead of just memorising it, so I am considering a case where a knight must choose $k = \{1,2,3\}$ out of $n=3$  weapons (Flail, Crossbow, Sword)

> For $k=1$:
>   $n(n-1)(n-k+1) = 3(3-1)(3-1+1) = 3(2)(3) = 18$
>   $\therefore 18$ possible outcomes for this experiment from sample size $k = 1$
>
> For $k=2$:
>   $n(n-1)(n-k+1) = 3(3-1)(3-2+1) = 3(2)(2) = 12$
>   $\therefore 12$ possible outcomes for this experiment from sample size $k = 2$
>
> and for $k=3$:
>   $n(n-1)(n-k+1) = 3(3-1)(3-2)(3-3+1) = 3(2)(1)(1) = 6$
>   $\therefore 6$ possible outcomes for this experiment from sample size $k = 3$

Obs.: $k \leq n$ makes sense to me

This is so weird. I think I don't quite get the $...$ in the Theorem's explanation. Why do I get 18 possible outcomes for k=1 if we can only have one weapon? Shouldn't this be 3 possible outcomes?

Likewise, for $k=2$ should this be one of the 6 scenarios below?

1. (Flail, Crossbow)
2. (Flail, Sword)
3. (Crossbow, Flail)
4. (Crossbow, Sword)
5. (Sword, Flail)
6. (Sword, Crossbow)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading the formula $n(n-1)\dots (n-k+1)$ wrong. Perhaps it would be easier to write it in this way:

$$\underbrace{n(n-1)\dots (n-k+1)}_{k \text{ terms}}$$

You only have $k$ terms in your formula because we are only picking $k$ things.

So in reality, in your example, what we get is $3$ ways to obtain a sample of size $1$. We have one term in the formula: the first term $n$ and in our example we say that $n=3$

For larger sizes, we always count down by one as well because after we pick something we will have one less option for the next choice.

Thus for the case of $k=2$ we will only have two terms and we count down one each time: $$3(2) = 6$$

And finally, we will never run into a problem of having a zero term because of the fact that $k \le n$

Answer (score 0):

Things you are missing:

- These scenarios (tuples technically) are ordered, so you have all orders of each.
- The dots signify a pattern, meaning roughly, continue the pattern until what ever is after the dots occurs. This leads to just 3 scenarios for your $k=1$ choices.

Answer (score 0):

If I have $n=3$ objects and I want to obtain a sample size $k = \{1,2,3\}$:

$k=1$, I can choose any of the three objects $\therefore n$
$k=2$, I can choose any of the remaining 2 objects.$\therefore (n-1)$
$k=3$, I can only choose the 1 object left $\therefore (n-2)$

Each row above represents $n(n-1)...(n-k+1)$

Lastly, there are $(3)(2)(1)=6$ ways to obtain a sample size of $k=3$.

Another example is for $n=10$ and $k=10$:

$k=1$, I can choose any of the 10 objects $\therefore n$ ways to pick 1 thing
$k=2$, I can choose any of the 9 remaining objects $\therefore (n-1)$ ways to pick 2 things
$k=3$, I can choose any of the 8 remaining objects $\therefore (n-2)$ ways to pick 3 things
$k=4$, I can choose any of the 7 remaining objects $\therefore (n-3)$ ways to pick 4 things
$k=5$, I can choose any of the 6 remaining objects $\therefore (n-4)$ ways to pick 5 things
$k=6$, I can choose any of the 5 remaining objects $\therefore (n-5)$ ways to pick 6 things
$k=7$, I can choose any of the 4 remaining objects $\therefore (n-6)$ ways to pick 7 things
$k=8$, I can choose any of the 3 remaining objects $\therefore (n-7)$ ways to pick 8 things
$k=9$, I can choose any of the 2 remaining objects $\therefore (n-8)$ ways to pick 9 things
$k=10$, I can only choose the 1 object $\therefore (n-9)$ way to pick 10 things

Again...
$n(n-1)...(n-k+1) = 3628800$ ways to obtain sample size of $k=10$